# OnClick element removed only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I don't understand the `.remove()` behavior here of `$postNav.remove();`
In the snippet below if the first time you click on "I'm a tag" the `.remove()` does work as expected deleting the `<li>` and `<ol>` respectively, but the second time you click on it only the `<li>` is deleted and not the `<ol>`. And i don't understand why the beaviour is different here, has the html remain the same…

```js
(function($) {
 $doc = $(document);
  
  var $container        = $('#main');
  var $pagePosts    = $container.find('div.post_list_wrapper ul');
 var $containerNav = $('section.section_things'); 
 var $postNav   = $('ol.pagenation');
 var $catName     = "";
 var $name     = "";
 var $page   = "1";
 var $clickTag   = "";


 $doc.ready( function() {   
  
   
   $("a[rel='tag']").addClass("ajax_tag");

 function get_posts(){
       
        $pagePosts.empty();
        $postNav.remove();
           $pagePosts.html("<li>Click Im a tag and scroll down you will see the ol stacking " + $page + "</li><div class='tag'><a rel='tag' href='/things/tag/xxxx/'>I'm a tag</a></div>");
        $containerNav.append("<ol class='pagenation'><a href='#' rel='tag'>" + $page + "Im the new ol</a></ol>");
              $page++;
        
         $("a[rel='tag']").addClass("ajax_tag");
         
   } //Get posts
  $container.on('click', "a[rel='tag'], .pagination a", function(event) {
     $this = $(this);
     event.preventDefault();
      
   if ($this.hasClass('ajax_tag')) {
       $clickTag = $this.text();
   } else {
       $page = parseInt($this.attr('href').replace(/\D/g,''));
   }
   get_posts();

   }); //onClick
   }); //Anonymous function
})(jQuery); //main function
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
}

/* THINGS ========================== */

.top .things .post_profile .category_label {
 padding: 9px 20px 5px;
 margin-right: 18px;
 background-color: #AE965C;
}


/* Pagenation ========================= */
.pagenation {
  text-align: center;
}
.pagenation li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.pagenation li.prev a,
.pagenation li.next a {
  position: relative;
}
.pagenation li.prev a:before,
.pagenation li.next a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #666666;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}
.pagenation li.prev a:before {
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.pagenation li.next a:before {
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.pagenation li a:hover:before {
  border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

.pagenation li.prev a:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.pagenation li.next a:before {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
}

#main > section.section_things {
 text-align: left;
}
.section_title {
 text-align: center;
}
.category_btn {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.category_btn li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 30px;
}
.category_btn li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.category_btn li a {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 min-width: 180px;
 padding: 6px;
 border: 2px solid #AE965C;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
Post list , unit
---------------------------------------------- */

.post_list_wrapper ul {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-box-pack: justify;
 -ms-flex-pack: justify;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.post_list_wrapper li {
 //width: 340px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
.post_list_wrapper li .eyecatch {
 position: relative;
}
.post_list_wrapper li .eyecatch .category_label {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 10;
}
.post_list_wrapper li .eyecatch .category_label a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.post_list_wrapper li .post_body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 212px;
}

.post_list_wrapper li .post_body .post_title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.post_list_wrapper li .post_body .tag {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
.category_btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px 15px;
}
.category_btn li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.category_btn li a {
  border: none;
}

.post_list_wrapper li {
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}
.post_list_wrapper li .post_body {
  min-height: inherit;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mainwrapper">
<main role="main" id="main">
    <section class="section_things">
      <h1 class="section_title">Things</h1>
      <ul class="category_btn futura">
        <li class="is_active"><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      </ul>
<div class="post_list_wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="eyecatch">
              <a href="/things/things-post.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/340x30"></a>

              <span class="category_label"><a href="/category/xxxxx/">SPECIAL</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="post_body">
              <a href="/things/things-post.html">
                   
                <div class="date">
                  <time datetime="2016-10-26">2016.10.26</time>
                </div>
                <h2 class="post_title">I'm a title</h2>
              </a>
              <div class="tag"><a rel='tag' href="/things/tag/xxxx/">I'm a tag</a></div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <ol class="pagenation">
        <li class="prev"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="is_active"><a href="/things/1/">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/things/2/">2</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ol>
 </section>
```

Comment: Please look at supplying a _Minimal_ example of your code

Comment: @haxxxton, that's what i tried to do but has I'm new in jQuery/JS i'm a bit afraid to screw up important information from the html which could explain my problem… still i'll have a look back to it to reduce has much as possible.

Comment: have a look at adding things to a http://jsfiddle.net/ and leaving just what's needed. The great thing about going through the process of creating a minimal example, is that you may remove something that makes things work again, and find where the sneaky typo/bug was hiding. Its a great practise to get into for trying to debug your own code :)

Comment: That's in fact exactly what i did, i think i have now pretty much the minimum i could without breaking everything, hope it give the code more readable. 
Thanks for the types it's effectively a good practice for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the `ol`'s stacking is that when you declare `$postNav = $('ol.pagenation')` you are traversing the DOM, and storing any found elements in the variable `$postNav`.

This means that later, any *newly* added `ol.pagenation` arent part of the elements that were found when you declared the variable. You can fix this by either:

1. calling `$('ol.pagenation').remove()` inside `get_posts`
2. updating the `$postNav` variable each time you add new `ol.pagenation`'s to the DOM like `$postNav = $('ol.pagenation');` so that next time `$postNav` has the latest found elements.

The benefit of option 2 is that if you need to access `$postNav` in any other functions, they will have access to the latest DOM elements. If, however, you dont need access to these elements elsewhere, option 1 may suffice.

**[JSFIDDLE OPTION 1](https://jsfiddle.net/sqn581vh/)**

**[JSFIDDLE OPTION 2](https://jsfiddle.net/sqn581vh/1/)**

Comment: Super thanks perfectly clear !! Accepted has answer.